# WEBGL: INVALID_VALUE: vertexAttribPointer: index out of range, INVALID_VALUE: enableVertexAttribArray: index out of range

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, lighting, normals

I read data from .obj file to draw a model.I draw the model correctly by using textures and vertexs. However when I want to draw using lighting, I have an error.
This error is WebGL:

> INVALID_VALUE: vertexAttribPointer: index out of range, INVALID_VALUE: enableVertexAttribArray: index out of range.

This code is my vertex shader

```
var VertexShaderCode =  "precision mediump float;\n"+
                         "attribute vec3 vertexPos;\n" +
                         "attribute vec3 vertexNormal;\n"+
                         "uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;\n" +
                         "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;\n" +
                         "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                         "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                         "    void main(void) {\n" +
                         "    gl_Position =  projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vertexPos, 1.0); \n" +
                         "    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n"+
                         "}\n";
```

this is my fragment shader code

```
var FragmentShaderCode =  "precision lowp float;"+
                           "uniform vec4 color;"+
                           "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;"+
                            "uniform vec3 u_Ambient_color;\n" +
                           "uniform sampler2D uSampler;"+
                           "uniform int texturecontrol;"+
                           "void main() { "+
                           "vec3 uColor;"+
                           "uColor = u_Ambient_color * vec3(color);"+
                           " if(texturecontrol !=0 )"+
                           " {"+
                           "  gl_FragColor =texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord)*vec4(uColor,color.a);"+
                           " }"+
                           " else{"+
                           "  gl_FragColor = vec4(uColor,color.a);"+
                           " }"+
                           "}"
```

and I try to draw like this.

```
if(this.Materyals[i].HasTexture){
    this.gl.uniform1i(this.FGlobe.PModeltexturecontrol,1)
    this.gl.uniform3fv(this.FGlobe.PModelAmbientColorLoc,this.Materyals[i].ambient)
    this.gl.uniform4fv(this.FGlobe.PModelColorLoc,this.Materyals[i].color)
    this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D,this.Materyals[i].Texture)
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.Materyals[i].textureCoord)
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.FGlobe.PModeltextCoordLoc,2,this.gl.FLOAT,false,0,0)  //şu anda this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER'a geçerli olan tamponun mevcut köşe tamponu nesnesinin genel bir vertex özniteliğine bağlanması ve düzenini belirtir.
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.FGlobe.PModeltextCoordLoc)
}else{            
    this.gl.uniform1i(this.FGlobe.PModeltexturecontrol,0)
    this.gl.uniform3fv(this.FGlobe.PModelAmbientColorLoc,this.Materyals[i].ambient)
    this.gl.uniform4fv(this.FGlobe.PModelColorLoc,this.Materyals[i].color)
    this.gl.disableVertexAttribArray(this.FGlobe.PModeltextCoordLoc)
}
this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.Materyals[i].normalBuffer)
this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.FGlobe.PModelnormalPos,3, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.FGlobe.PModelnormalPos)


this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.Materyals[i].vertexBuffer)
this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.FGlobe.PModelvertexPos,3, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.FGlobe.PModelvertexPos)
this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES,0, this.Materyals[i].TriCnt*3);
}
```

Any ideas?What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying incorrect attribute index for `vertexAttribPointer` and `enableVertexAttribArray`. You haven't provided code for setting these values, but you should double-check that there're no typos of getting attributes and uniforms locations in your code.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect it's because you have an unused attribute vertexNormal. If you add a line into the code:

```
var VertexShaderCode =  "precision mediump float;\n"+
                     "attribute vec3 vertexPos;\n" +
                     "attribute vec3 vertexNormal;\n"+
                     "uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;\n" +
                     "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;\n" +
                     "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                     "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                     "    void main(void) {\n" +
                     "    vertexNormal; \n" +               /* This line here */
                     "    gl_Position =  projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vertexPos, 1.0); \n" +
                     "    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n"+
                     "}\n";
```

things will probably work fine. If this is the case, it's likely because WebGL optimized away the attribute since it wasn't used.

Comment: That happened to me, I just removed the unused attribute at javascript side and the message vanished.